# Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac' in ionic 3

Tags: node.js, ionic3

I built an ionic app with ionic 3 on ionic-cli 3.19.0 and later updated it to 3.20.0
It stopped building the apk and started giving this error->
ti-ionic3/platforms/android/src/com/adobe/phonegap/push/FCMService.java:393: error: constructor Builder in class Builder
 cannot be applied to given types;
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, channelID);
                   ^
  required: Context
  found: Context,String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.